# SSRS - Parameter - SELECT ALL vs ALL - How to remove ALL option

Tags: visual-studio, t-sql, reporting-services, report, ssas

Please look at this ss [image: Screenshot]

I am using SSRS 2008 + pulling data from a cube and made Country my parameter.

I want to keep "Select ALL" option but remove "ALL" option.

How would I go about doing that?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the ALLMEMBERS function with the CHILDREN function.

http://www.bidn.com/blogs/ChrisAlbrektson/bidn-blog/1452/mdx-ssrs-how-to-remove-the-all-member-from-your-parameter <-- will show you what I mean

Comment: Thanks...I am using drag and drop option so would I have to change all "ALLMEMBERS" to "CHILDREN?"

Comment: Sorry,not sure what exactly you mean by drag and drop option. Go to the 'Datasets' option in your 'Report data' window, locate the dataset that contains your MDX query and change the ALLMEMBERS function to CHILDREN.

Comment: Got it...I had to edit the query for the hidden dataset inorder to chnage ALLMEMBERS ro CHILDREN. Thank you